# Update stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I write stored procedure for update.

```
create procedure sp_videos_updateviews (@videoid varchar(50),@ret int output)
as
   set @ret = update videos set [views]=[views]+1 
   where videoid = @videoid

   if(@ret>1)
   begin
     set @ret=1
   end
   else
   begin
     set @ret=0
   end
```

but it is giving error like this

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'update'.

Comment: For performance reasons, you'd better NOT prefix your stored procedure with SP.    When you do that, SQL Server will first search in the master DB to find the stored procedure, and only if it doesn't find it there, it will look for it in the current DB.

Comment: thank you Mr.Frederik gheysels. You r saying that not to prefix sp then how can i write, like  "create procedure videos_insert " is it ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surya,

From what I gather you are looking to return from the proc a 1 or 0 depending on if any records were updated from your proc. I agree that @@ROWCOUNT is where you should go, try this code:

```
create procedure proc_videos_updateviews (@videoid varchar(50),@ret int output) 
as 

update videos set [views]=[views]+1
where videoid = @videoid

if(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
begin
    set @ret = 1
end
else
begin
    set @ret = 0
end
```

Answer (score 6):

You can't set a variable to an UPDATE statement. If you are trying to get the row count at the end of the update, try this:

```
UPDATE vidoes SET [views] = [views] + 1
WHERE videoid = @videoid
SET @ret = @@ROWCOUNT
```

Comment: The first line of your procedure attempts to set the value of an `int` variable to be an update statement. I think what you want to set is the number of rows affected by the update statement. That is what the code I have given you does.

Comment: ok then code will   update videos set [views]=[views]+1 
set @ret= (select count(*) from videos
where videoid=@videoid) 
if(@ret>1)
set @ret=1
else
set@ret=0 am i right

Comment: No, just replace the one incorrect line in your stored procedure with the two lines in my answer. The rest can stay as it is.